# sorting by binary (number of ones in a binary)

Tags: postgresql

I have a database with permissions encoded as a binary flag stores in a smallint in postgres.
This means that I can have 2, 4, 8, 16 or maybe  12 in a column.
Now if I 'order by' on that column 16 would be considered higher than 12 even though 12 has two 1's in it and 16 only has one 1's (01100 vs 10000).

If you think of 1's as a checked checkbox on a permission page, and 0's as not checked checkboxes, 12 has two checks and 16 only has one check.
I would like to sort by the on with most checks.

Is it possible to somehow sort by number of 1's in the binary?

Answer (score 2):

If you cast the value to a `bit` data type and then convert that to a string. If you remove the zeros from the string, yYou can order by the length of the string.

```
order by length(replace(permissions::bit(8)::text, '0', ''))
```

assuming you are using 8 bits, otherwise change the cast.

```
with data (permissions) as (
  values 
    (12),
    (0),
    (16),
    (4)
)
select permissions::bit(8) as bits, permissions
from data
order by length(replace(permissions::bit(8)::text, '0', ''))
```

will return:

```
bits     | permissions
---------+------------
00000000 |           0
00010000 |          16
00000100 |           4
00001100 |          12
```

You need to decide on how you want to order values with the same number of bits however (16 and 4 in the above example), e.g. by adding another sort column as a tie breaker

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but it will get very ugly:

```
CREATE TABLE bits (bits INTEGER NOT NULL);
INSERT into bits(bits) select gs FROM generate_series(0,16) gs;

SELECT bits
FROM bits
ORDER BY (bits & 1 = 1)::integer
        + (bits & 2 = 2)::integer
        + (bits & 4 = 4)::integer
        + (bits & 8 = 8)::integer
        + (bits & 16 = 16)::integer
        , bits -- tiebreaker
        ;
```

---

Results:

```
CREATE TABLE
INSERT 0 17
 bits 
------
    0
    1
    2
    4
    8
   16
    3
    5
    6
    9
   10
   12
    7
   11
   13
   14
   15
(17 rows)
```